# How to make bash scripts execute when clicked upon?

Tags: 12.04, unity, bash

I am trying to create a bash script for the Dash home button, as I am trying to fully replace the Unity dock with the Cairo Dock. Unfortunately, I have been unable to make it so that the script only runs when I click on it.

How can I make a bash script execute when clicked upon?

If it helps, here is my code:

```
#\bin\bash

xdotool key Super
```

Comment: It's `#!/bin/bash` not `#/bin/bash`. We all make mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

The *shebang* is wrong, type this instead :

```
#!/bin/bash

xdotool key Super
```

and set the execution bit on the script.

Comment: set the eXecution bit by opening Terminal and typing `sudo chmod +x <path/to/bash_file.bsh>`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04, you should be able to do this simply by right-clicking the file, clicking `properties` in the drop-down menu, going to the `permissions` tab and checking the `allow executing file as program` button. If this does not work you can open a terminal and run this command:
`sudo chmod +x /path/to/your/scriptfile`. I hope I helped!